# Add effects depending on browser performance

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

I'm working on my new portfolio and I want to use a complex javascript (for animating, moving, effecting dom elements) and i going to do as much as possible optimization to maximize the performance. BUT I can't prepare for all the case with my site will be faced. So i started to looking for a script with I can check the browser performance (maximum in a few seconds) and based on the performance test results I can set the number of displayed and calculated effects on the page.

So is there any way to check browser performance and set the optimal number of applied effect on a page?

Comment: The short answer would be "No". But you can pull some stats like OS, browser versions and draw your own conclusions. I’m not sure it will improve the user experience though...

Comment: But th performance includes the hardware too so i can not work just with browsver vendors and their versions. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: All detection tools given at the client level is restricted to software/browser. You can’t test the hardware, but you can use "hardware-optimized" client-side functions. But you will never "know" how they perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, use CSS transforms/transitions instead of pure-js effects, as the former are usually hardware accelerated and thus orders of magnitude faster.

Even if you don't use CSS transforms, you can detect support for them using e.g. modernizr, and if supported, you can assume that the browser is very modern and has pretty good performance in general. Take a look at [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame), it automatically throttles the framerate.

Comment: Yeah, I use CSS3 when it possible but for parallax scrolling I have to use seme Javascript calculation. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

By the way thanks for the framerate suggestion. I think it's getting me closer to the goal.

Comment: +1 Just because the browser is "modern", the hardware running the browser can be pretty weak, as is the case on many mobile devices. Testing performance would be nearly impossible in all cases, but using tools like modernizr etc. will narrow browser capabilities down, for what it’s worth.